# How to confirm request in Parity

Tags: contract-development, web3js, parity, signature

[enter link description here](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/JSONRPC-signer-module#signer_confirmrequest)I send a transaction with contract. I use unlock account to account it. It can skip the first confirm. Which is asked to confirm deploy. But it can't skip the second confirm, the function execution. Just as the picture show.

[image]

I search the JSONRPC of Parity. And found a JSONRPC named [confirmRequest](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/JSONRPC-signer-module#signer_confirmrequest), I think it's maybe useful. But when I call it, it returns "Method not found"...

So how to confirm this request? Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Oh.. I use unlockAccount twice (Once before deploy contract, once before send transaction) and that is solved... But the confirmRequest JSONRPC still can't work, right?

Answer (score 1):

In order to use the `signer_confirmRequest` method, you have to enable the signer module in your `config.toml` file in the `[rpc]` section, like this:

```
[rpc]
apis = ["web3", "eth", "net", ...other modules..., "signer"]
```